# Iterating over csv file

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to open a downloaded csv file and I end up doing so and printing it out to make sure I did it correctly. But when ever I try to check a value or multiple characters in the list my sequence_counter always returns zero. Any help is appreciated thanks!

```
import csv
from sys import argv

#Error Checking
n = len(argv)
sequence_counter = 0
if n != 3:
    print("Error")
#Read user command & choose file
else:
    with open(argv[1], "r") as csv_data:
        #csv_data.read()
        csv_data = csv.reader(csv_data)
        #print out each row

        for row in csv_data:
            print(row)

    with open(argv[2], "r") as csv_seq:
        #csv_seq.read()
        csv_seq = csv.reader(csv_seq)
        #print out each row
        for row in csv_seq:
            print(row)
            print("\n")
        for row in csv_seq:
            if "A" in csv_seq:
                sequence_counter += 1 

print(sequence_counter)
```

## How many times DNA repeats

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Have you done any debugging?

Answer (score 0):

You went through the entire CSV printing the rows. When you try again, the file pointer is at the end of the file so there is nothing left to read. You can `seek(0)` to go back to the start of the file. One must be careful with `seek` - unless you open in binary mode, python inserts a decode layer in between your read and the file system read. You can `seek(0)` to reset that intermediate buffer but cannot generally seek elsewhere in the file.

```
with open(argv[2], "r") as csv_seq:
    #csv_seq.read()
    csv_seq = csv.reader(csv_seq)
    #print out each row
    for row in csv_seq:
        print(row)
        print("\n")
    csv_seq.seek(0)
    for row in csv_seq:
        if "A" in csv_seq:
            sequence_counter += 1
```